# How can I add metadata to MP3s for Windows Media player

Tags: windows-media-player, metadata

I have a few downloaded podcast MP3s, and I'd like to set up some basic metadata for them (artist name, album for date) in Windows Media Player.  Is there a way to do this without downloading a program (create a metadata file or the like)?  Otherwise, can you recommend a decent program to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the list view, click on the field to make it editable. It's kind of like a slow double-click.

Edit: think I may have misunderstood. Do you mean edit metadata on downloaded podcasts within WMP or to setup a regular set of metadata for specific podcasts?

Comment: I think what you suggest is accurate.

Comment: B, you're talking about in WMP, right?  or in an Explorer window?  clarify your answer for us pls.

Comment: In WMP.  You select the song you're interested in in the library, and edit the fields.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it either via media player itself, or by going to the download folder, right-clicking the files, hitting properties, and the details tab. There you can input anything from track name, contributing artist/ album artist, album, genre, and date.

I find the folder route to be simpler for podcasts in particular as you can batch edit specific tracks rather than nitpick from a list.